# Get only CommonPrefixes from an Amazon S3 ListObjects

Tags: php, amazon-s3

This is my code

```
$result = $s3Client->ListObjects(array(
   'Bucket' => __AWS_BUCKET,
   'Prefix' => 'cats/',
   'Delimiter' => '/',
));
```

Is there a way to get only [CommonPrefixes] in the response. Now it returns [Contents, Prefix, Name....]
As there is limit of 1000 objects in one request and I don't want Content index or Keys index.